# Upgrading Swagger to OpenAPI v3 - Objects are all JSON blobs after upgrade - Not fields

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am upgrading my application to the OpenAPI v3 Swagger.

Note: Images are not from the system in question. for security reasons I cannot post real screenshots.

**From:**
io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0

[image: Springfox layout example of Swagger]

**To:**
org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0
io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.10

Now when I look at each of the GET requests I see the JSON blob that I have to replace with the data I need to send. And it works. Here are two images showing the format of the overall page and the format of the method call with a JSON blob.

[image: Springdoc individual method example]
[image: Springdoc overall layout example]

Problem is that previously I had a list of fields nicely presenting which were "query"/"header"/etc. and their datatype (see 1st image). This is lost with the JSON format.

Is there a setting I'm missing? I'm doing this via a Java class in SpringBoot with @Bean methods, so I'd prefer not to have to put annotations on every one of my operations.

Comment: Do you use Springfox or Springdoc, and what version before and after the upgrade? Can you post the code and annotations of a sample controller and/or DTO that has this issue? Can you also post screenshots of Swagger UI from before the upgrade (showing the "list of fields nicely presenting which were "query"/"header"/etc. and their datatype") and after the upgrade (showing the "JSON blob")?